# Rolling file log with Serilog in c#

Tags: c#, serilog

All log files need to be written per day in a rolling mode.
However, I have a question how can I implement the rolling log file for the current file without date,
we need the following logic:

.log => current log file

.log.date => old log files,

This the code what I implement however after executing I found the current file with the date.

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.RollingFile(@"C:\project\SerilogFile.txt", retainedFileCountLimit: 7)
            .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: how would you want  it to roll over?

Comment: I want the current log file without date and the oldest log file with the date however if there a new log file coming then the current file will be with the date and new one without a date in the end.

Comment: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-rollingfile/issues/59

Comment: Do you have any Idea how can I implement this logic using the framework Serilog ?